# How can I specify the location of one file for program configuration without specifying the location for all C compilers in Unix?

Tags: c++, c, unix, compiler-errors, configuration

I am trying to compile a program called Clustal Omega on my Unix operating system. I do not have root access. Clustal Omega requires argtable2 to compile. I installed argtable2 in my home/user/bin/ and the Clustal Omega installation instructions suggest I use:

> ./configure CFLAGS='~/bin/argtable2-13/include'

Which specifies the location of the argtable2.h file.

However, when I run this I get an error because it tries to retrieve gcc and g++ C compilers from that location as well, when actually they are in the root/bin/ which I cannot edit.

I've tried:

> ./configure CC='/opt/apps/gcc/6.3.0/bin/gcc' CXX='/opt/apps/gcc/6.3.0/bin/g++' CFLAGS='~/bin/argtable2-13/include'

and

> ./configure CFLAGS='~/bin/argtable2-13/include' LDFLAGS='~/bin/argtable2-13/lib'

which was suggested elsewhere. Neither are able to complete configuration.

How can I specify the location of the argtable2-13 required files without specifying the location of all the C compilers?

Thanks, everyone, but the following did not work either:

> ./configure CPPFLAGS='~/bin/argtable2-13/include'
>
> ./configure --with-argtable2.h='~/bin/argtable2-13/include'
>
> ./configure --with-argtable2='~/bin/argtable2-13/include'
>
> ./configure CFLAGS='-I ~/bin/argtable2-13/include'

Not sure if this is the right thing to put in  but I don't know which program to request --help from?

The error is:

```
checking argtable2.h presence... no 
checking for argtable2.h... no 
configure: error: Could not find argtable2.h. Try $ ./configure CFLAGS='-Iyour-argtable2-include-path
```

Comment: `CFLAGS` needs to be the flags you want to add. The directory itself is not a flag. You probably want `CFLAGS='-I ~/bin/argtable2-13/include'`. Similarly for `LDFLAGS`. If that isn't the issue please show the exact errors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to specify include directory for configure script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958904/how-to-specify-include-directory-for-configure-script)

Comment: The error is: checking argtable2.h presence... no
checking for argtable2.h... no
configure: error: Could not find argtable2.h. Try $ ./configure CFLAGS='-Iyour-argtable2-include-path

Comment: Please edit your Q to include important error messages. Putting them in comments just forces new readers to go thru all the comments to understand the problem definition. Use the `{}` tool from the Edit menu on mouse-selected text to get proper formatting for `data/code/errMsgs`.  Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

There are two main issues:

1. `CFLAGS` needs to be the flags you want to add (not just the directory). Similarly for `LDFLAGS`.
2. Shell expansions (tilda prefix in this case) are not performed on the strings passed to `configure`. Use expanded path.

Combining that the configure command should be:

```
./configure CFLAGS="-I /home/<username>/bin/include" LDFLAGS="-L /home/<username>/bin/lib"
```